# SimpleDateFormat.format() gives invalid Date

Tags: java, datetime-format

```
final static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

This method generated an invalid date:

```
public static String getDate(double seconds) {
  Date date = new Date((long)(seconds * 1000));
  return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Somehow `1465235513.09794` came as `"2015-06-31T02:33:31.921+0000"` - interesting part is June 31st.

Any clue?

Comment: edit your java code to code view

Comment: @DonaldWu code was posted, just not formatted

Comment: return 2016-06-06T17:51:53.097+0000 for me ....

Comment: OP, prove it my providing a working code, and by running it yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess, are you using this in multi-thread program. If that's the case, SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe. I would rather move the dateFormat into getDate() method.
From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Or use Java 8 [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) & [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as Jon Skeet suggested.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

> A formatter created from a pattern can be used as many times as
>   necessary, it is immutable and is thread-safe.

or use Joda time (if you can't use Java 8 for whatever reasons) as Adrian Shum suggested.

Comment: Or better, use `java.time` if at all possible, as the formatters there are thread-safe and the API is generally much cleaner...

Comment: Or, for those who need to stick with Java 7 or earlier, use JODA Time :)

Comment: Its running inside of multi-threaded process (Apache Storm). So threads might be the case. Thanks man..it was driving me nuts.. I couldn't even recreate the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.. I appreciate it.. will upgrade to Java 8 at earliest opportunity then.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project. Use that now, to save your sanity from the mess that is the legacy date-time classes. No need to wait for Java 8. Also, that back-port is further adapted to Android specifically in the ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    double seconds = 1465235513.09794;
    Date date = new Date((long)(seconds * 1000));   //1465235513097
    String reqDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(reqDate); // 2016-06-06T23:21:53.097+0530
```

Refer epoch time if there is any confusion